# Bigquery Invalid Timestamp

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I was trying to update the table but I got this error instead:

> Error 400: Invalid timestamp: '2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346 +0000 UTC', invalidQuery])

How do I convert this to timestamp?

Here's the code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
}
defer client.Close()

q := client.Query("UPDATE myTable SET name = "John Doe", date_updated = TIMESTAMP("2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346 +0000 UTC") WHERE id = 10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
q := client.Query("UPDATE myTable SET name = 'John Doe', date_updated = TIMESTAMP('2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346') WHERE id = 10"
```

To [set timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp) use `+00`:

```
q := client.Query("UPDATE myTable SET name = 'John Doe', date_updated = TIMESTAMP('2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346+00') WHERE id = 10"
```

Comment: The date value `2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346 +0000 UTC` is from another database. How do I removed the `+0000 UTC`?

Comment: Try `select TIMESTAMP(REPLACE('2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346 +0000 UTC', ' +0000 UTC', ''))`

Comment: `select TIMESTAMP(RTRIM('2021-03-02 05:34:51.161346 +0000 UTC', ' +0000 UTC'))`